# How to catch and handle only specific Oracle exceptions?

Tags: oracle, exception

From [this](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm) and [this](http://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/exceptions/named_system.php) i guess, that there is no predefined Named System Exceptions for ORA-00955.

How can I rewrite the following to catch only the error ORA-00955?

```
begin
      EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE S_TEST START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1';
exception when OTHERS then
    Null;
end;
```

BTW Is there any syntax to catch errors by just providing the error-codes?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have two options:

---

Refer to the exception directly by number:

```sql
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE S_TEST START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1';
EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      IF SQLCODE = -955 THEN
        NULL; -- suppresses ORA-00955 exception
      ELSE
         RAISE;
      END IF;
END;
```

---

Other option is to use `EXCEPTION_INIT` Pragma directive to bind a known Oracle error number to user defined exception;

```sql
DECLARE
   name_in_use exception; --declare a user defined exception
   pragma exception_init( name_in_use, -955 ); --bind the error code to the above 
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE SEQUENCE S_TEST START WITH 1 INCREMENT BY 1';
EXCEPTION
    when name_in_use then
       null; --suppress ORA-00955 exception
END;
```

---

> BTW Is there any syntax to catch errors by just providing the error-codes?

Yes, I've demonstrated it in the first example

Further reading for variations on this:

- [Oracle Reference Documentation on Handling PL/SQL Exceptions](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B13789_01/appdev.101/b10807/07_errs.htm)

Comment: can't I go just go without the when others raise lines ?

Comment: @bernd_k yes you do that, it goes as an unhandled exception however

Comment: Please add a raise in your WHEN OTHERS when the `sqlcode` is NOT 955 =)

Comment: The OP may still want to have other errors raised. Your Exception block "as is" behaves exactly as a WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL. I think the OP wants something a bit more precise and subtle.

Comment: @VincentMalgrat You're correct.

Answer (score 5):

Similar to what Sathya has already suggested, but I like to avoid `when others` completely if possible - an unhandled exception is usually the correct outcome for exceptions you aren't specifically handling:

```sql
create sequence foo;
/*
sequence FOO created.
*/
declare
  name_is_already_used_955 exception;
  pragma exception_init(name_is_already_used_955,-955);
begin
  execute immediate 'create sequence foo';
exception when name_is_already_used_955 then null;
end;
/
/*
anonymous block completed
*/
```

Comment: That is exactly what I condensed from Sathyas proposals myself.